# Android news app UI showing empty space on the top of gridview?

Tags: android, user-interface

I hope all of you are doing great I am developing news app but there white space on the top card view I have used card view as parent constrain layout as a child.

This screenshot [image: Emulator]

```
    below my news_items.xml where I have implemented article list



 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"

        app:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
        app:cardElevation="6dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/article_Image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:text="TextView"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/article_Author"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/article_Author"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="8dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
                android:textColor="#DE000000"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/article_Image" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/article_Title"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="8dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
                android:textColor="#DE000000"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/article_Author"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/article_Date"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="8dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
                android:textColor="#DE000000"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/article_Title"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/article_Description"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="8dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
                android:textColor="#DE000000"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:padding="50dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/article_Date" />




            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/copy_Button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="48dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="48dp"
                android:background="#00FFFFFF"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/article_Description"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/share_button"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_copy" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/share_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:background="#00FFFFFF"
                android:padding="20dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_share" />
            <!--<LinearLayout-->
            <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
            <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
            <!--android:layout_gravity="center"-->
            <!--android:orientation="horizontal">-->

            <!--<ImageButton-->
            <!--android:id="@+id/copy_Button"-->
            <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
            <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
            <!--android:layout_below="@id/article_Description"-->
            <!--android:layout_weight="1"-->
            <!--android:background="@drawable/ic_copy"-->
            <!--android:maxLines="1"-->
            <!--android:text="textview1" />-->


            <!--<ImageButton-->
            <!--android:id="@+id/share_button"-->
            <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
            <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
            <!--android:layout_weight="0"-->
            <!--android:background="@drawable/ic_share"-->
            <!--android:text="textview2" />-->

            <!--</LinearLayout>-->
            -->
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>





</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    **below my MainActivity where I am using bottom NavigationBar and hosting four news.**


    public class MainActivity extends BottomBarHolderActivity implements AllJazeeraFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener, BBCFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener, CNNFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener, CBCNewsFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

        //    private ApiService apiService;
        public static final String url_key = "urlKey";
        final int Bottom_CAPACITY = 7;
        public ArrayList<Article> articleList = new ArrayList<>();


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);

            Article article = new Article(Parcel.obtain());
            article.setUrl(article.getUrl());
            Intent i = new Intent(this, DetailActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("urlKey", article);
    //        // using the (String name, Parcelable value) overload!
    //        startActivity(i);

            NavigationPage page1 = new NavigationPage("All Jazeera", ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.alljazeera), AllJazeeraFragment.newInstance());
            NavigationPage page2 = new NavigationPage("BBC", ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.bbc_icon), CNNFragment.newInstance());
            NavigationPage page3 = new NavigationPage("CNN", ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.cnn_icon), AllJazeeraFragment.newInstance());
            NavigationPage page4 = new NavigationPage("CBC", ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.cbc_icon), CBCNewsFragment.newInstance());
            //NavigationPage page5 = new NavigationPage("Menu", ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.icon_menu), Menu.newInstance());
            List<NavigationPage> navigationPages = new ArrayList<>(Bottom_CAPACITY);
            Boolean navigation = navigationPages.size() > 6;
            navigationPages.add(page1);
            navigationPages.add(page2);
            navigationPages.add(page3);
            navigationPages.add(page4);


            super.setupBottomBarHolderActivity(navigationPages);


        }


        public void onClicked() {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

below my AllJazeraFragment other fragment news classes the same

    public class AllJazeeraFragment extends Fragment {


        public NewsAdapter adapter;
        public ArrayList<Article> articleList = new ArrayList();
        RecyclerView recyclerView;

        private AllJazeeraFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener listener;

        public static AllJazeeraFragment newInstance() {
            return new AllJazeeraFragment();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alljazeera_fragment, container, false);

            NewsInterface apiService = NewsClient.getApiService();
            Call<ArticleResponse> call = apiService.getAllJazeera();

            call.enqueue(new Callback<ArticleResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<ArticleResponse> call, Response<ArticleResponse> response) {

                    articleList = new ArrayList(response.body().getArticles());
                    recyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
                    adapter = new NewsAdapter(articleList);
                    RecyclerView.LayoutManager eLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
                    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(eLayoutManager);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<ArticleResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });

            return rootView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Context context) {
            super.onAttach(context);
            if (context instanceof AllJazeeraFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
                listener = (AllJazeeraFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
            } else {
                throw new RuntimeException(context.toString() + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDetach() {
            super.onDetach();
            listener = null;
        }

        public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        }


    }

    alljazera_fragment.xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

My Adapter class where I have implemented news adapter

public class NewsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
    public static final String urlKey = "urlKey";
    public static final String ImageKey = "imageKey";
    private final List<Article> articleList;
    Context context;
    private ClipboardManager myClipboard;
    private ClipData myClip;

    public NewsAdapter(List<Article> articleList) {

        this.articleList = articleList;

    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public NewsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.
                from(viewGroup.getContext()).
                inflate(R.layout.news_item, viewGroup, false);
        return new NewsViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final NewsViewHolder newsViewHolder, final int i) {
        final Article article = articleList.get(i);
        SimpleDateFormat input = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
        SimpleDateFormat output = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

        Date d = new Date();
        try {
            d = input.parse(article.getPublishedAt());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        String formatted = output.format(d);

        newsViewHolder.articleAuthor.setText(article.getAuthor());
        newsViewHolder.articleTitle.setText(article.getTitle());
        newsViewHolder.articleDescription.setText(article.getDescription());
        newsViewHolder.articleDate.setText(formatted);
        //newsViewHolder.articleDate.setText(article.getPublishedAt());
        Picasso.get().load(article.getUrlToImage()).into(newsViewHolder.articleImage);
        newsViewHolder.copy_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {


                myClipboard = (ClipboardManager) v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);


                myClip = ClipData.newPlainText("label", newsViewHolder.articleTitle.getText().toString());
                myClipboard.setPrimaryClip(myClip);
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Copied to clipboard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
        newsViewHolder.shareButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
                String articleDescription = article.getDescription();
                String articleTitle = article.getTitle();
                sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, articleDescription);
                sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, articleTitle);
                v.getContext().startActivity((Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share using")));
            }
        });
        newsViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), DetailActivity.class);
//start the activity from the view/context

                intent.putExtra("urlKey", article.getUrl());
                //intent.putExtra("imageKey", article.getUrlToImage());
                view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return articleList.size();
    }


    public final class NewsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // TextView articleAuthor, articleTitle, articleDescription, articleUrl;
        //  ImageView articleImage;

        @BindView(R.id.article_Image)
        ImageView articleImage;
        @BindView(R.id.article_Author)
        TextView articleAuthor;
        @BindView(R.id.article_Title)
        TextView articleTitle;

        @BindView(R.id.article_Description)
        TextView articleDescription;
        @BindView(R.id.article_Date)
        TextView articleDate;
        @BindView(R.id.share_button)
        ImageButton shareButton;
        @BindView(R.id.copy_Button)
        ImageButton copy_Button;


        public NewsViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);

            if (context != null) {
                Typeface typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.roboto_black);
                articleTitle.setTypeface(typeface);

            }

        }

    }
}
```

Please help me to solve the issue,

regards, Yodgorbek

Comment: It would be more helpful if you would use the same news story from the same news provider for comparison. Here you have one story from "All Jazeera" (which you misspelled!) and another story from CNN--making it difficult to see what is really going wrong with your code.

Comment: I have changed in my code thanks for your attention and giving a nice feedback I really appreacited that. What do you think what is the main problem or I have to add additional codes on my post

Comment: You make it difficult to see which view could be causing the issue, because you are using two different news stories. Please edit your post changing the screen shot and use the same news story for both situations...then I will have another look at it.

Comment: HI I have done as you told me please check update code and screenshot thanks

Comment: @Barns did you check my code

Comment: Yes. I would suggest that you use either `ConstraintLayout` or `RelativeLayout` either will give you more control over the positioning of the view elements. :: Also you might want to change the `layout_width` attributes of the `ImageView` "article_Image" to `match_parent` and add an attribute to scale that image as needed--perhaps  `scaleType=fitXY` or `scaleType=centerCrop`.  ::  In general, I also suggest you make more use of `marginStart` and `marginEnd`. You should also explore the difference for `android:gravity` and `android:layout_gravity`.

Comment: where I have to use marginStart and MarginEnd

Comment: I have done as you told me I have used constraintlayout but there are empty space on the top

Comment: @Barns I have updated code please check when you are free regards, Yodgorbek

Comment: Do you also have updated screenshots?

Comment: just wait I will updated

Comment: @Barns I have updated questions as well right now it is white large empty space on the top of cardview

Comment: @Barns now it is showing copy and sharing button both emulator and realdeice

Comment: I posted a suggestion of how to approach the cardview. Please have a look and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this layout will give you the result you wish to achieve. This is just the `CardView` you will probably want to embed it in a `FrameLayout`.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/article_Image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/automobile"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/article_Author"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:textColor="#DE000000"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_below="@id/article_Image"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/article_Title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:textColor="#DE000000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_below="@id/article_Author"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/article_Date"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:textColor="#DE000000"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_below="@id/article_Title"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/article_Description"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/really_long_text_250"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="8dp"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:textColor="#DE000000"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/article_Date"
        android:layout_above="@id/buttonContainer"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttonContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        >
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/copy_Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#00FFFFFF"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_event_black_24dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/share_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#00FFFFFF"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_contacts_black_24dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

---

**Note:**

I choose `RelativeLayout` because I am more familiar with it.

Please let me know if you have any issues or the layout does not fulfill the need design specs.

Don't for get to correct the spelling of "Al Jazeera".